# ¿Existe en Español un adjetivo para "(de algo dicho) no claro y usualmente queriendo decir lo contrario de lo que parece decir"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En Inglés tienen un adjetivo llamado "backhanded" que significa:

> (de algo dicho) no claro y usualmente queriendo decir lo contrario de
> lo que parece decir

[Backhanded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/backhanded)

Existe algo así en Español? Una traducción que usualmente se hace es ambiguo, pero ambiguo no es lo mismo, porque ambiguo no quiere decir usualmente lo contrario de lo que se quiere decir, si es ambiguo es no claro y puede ser de una forma u otra pero no preferentemente de una.

Answer (score 1):

> **backhanded remark**: A backhanded remark seems pleasant but may really be a criticism or mean something unkind:
> a **backhanded compliment**

Si le haces una crítica solapada a alguien disfrazándola de comentario halagüeño la traducción dependera de que significado capte la persona porque al ser contradictorio, puede tomar uno o varios; positivos, negativos o ninguno, algo como comentario constructivo, positivo, sincero, malintencionado desubicado, invasivo, inoportuno, condescendiente o falso.

"Backhanded compliment" es un comentario halagüeño, pero que en el fondo es una crítica, p.ej. ejemplo insinuarle que su departamento es acogedor cuando lo que quiero decir en realidad es que es pequeño o decirle a alguien que se ve bien con cualquier cosa que se ponga cuando en el fondo el mensaje que estoy enviando es que se ha dejado estar o que no anda presentable.

Eso de equívoco, ambiguo, velado/da, contradictorio o "con/De doble intención" me suena a mala traducción, no es muy preciso porque la intención es clara de parte de quien la hace.

"Lanzar/tirar Indirectas" es para hacer recapacitar a alguien o que se de cuenta o capte el mensaje, pero no es precisamente "it's backhanded"

> indirecta: Expresión que sirve para dar a entender una cosa pero sin decirla de manera clara y precisa.
> "no entendió las indirectas que le lanzaba la chica"

> indirecta: 2. f. Dicho o medio de que alguien se vale para no significar explícita o claramente algo, y darlo, sin embargo, a entender.

> sarcastic: using remarks that clearly mean the opposite of what you say, in order to hurt someone's feelings or to humorously criticize something:
> a sarcastic comment/remark

Creo que cuando dices que se refiere a lo opuesto de lo que quiere decir es en realidad "sarcasm" porque "backhanded" es en realidad es positivo y negativo al mismo tiempo dependiendo de como lo entienda el receptor, si es que lo llegara a hacer.

Comment: @Ananias Para mi no hay una traducción exacta, no usaría ambiguo, contradictorio. Tal vez crítica velada, implícita o disfrazada pero no es precisamente backhanded. Las cosas en español no se dicen igual. Depende de lo que entienda el receptor y como adjetivo no funciona bien. Ahora si en la región del OP lo usan, bien por él.

Answer (score 1):

No encontré un término exacto, pero aquí hay algunos que se usan coloquialmente dependiendo del efecto que describen.

1. Venenoso
2. Mordaz
3. Sarcástico
4. Solapado
5. Ambiguo
6. Piadoso

Comment: son sustantivos, la pregunta era sobre un adjetivo

Comment: Tiene razón, pasé por alto ese detalle. Lo editaré.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizo una frase de [theidioms.com](https://www.theidioms.com/backhanded-compliment/) para dar contexto:

> The husband said the food was tasty, which seemed like a backhanded compliment since he ate only two spoonfuls.

> El esposo dijo que la comida estaba rica, lo que parecía un comentario ambiguo ya que solo comió dos cucharadas.

#### Retintín

Modo de hablar, por lo común para zaherir a alguien. [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/retint%C3%ADn)

> El esposo dijo que la comida estaba rica, lo que parecía un comentario con retintín ya que solo comió dos cucharadas.

#### Sorna

Tono burlón con que se expresa ironía. [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/sorna?m=form)

> El esposo dijo que la comida estaba rica, lo que parecía un comentario con sorna ya que solo comió dos cucharadas.

Comment: son sustantivos, la pregunta era sobre un adjetivo

Answer (score 0):

**Backhand** (tener la mano hacia atrás), **Backhanded** (revés), **In a backhanded way** (De una manera indirecta), **Backhanded compliments** (cumplido indirecto).

[image]

> **Backhanded** (revés)  (adj.)
>
> 1765, "hecho con la mano vuelta hacia atrás", de "backhand" (qv). El
> sentido figurado
>
> "oblicuo en significado, indirecto; ambivalente, sarcástico", es de
> 1777.
>
> Relacionado con Backhandedly y Backhandedness.
>
> - A esto, añadir la descripción de algunos diccionarios al respecto.
>
> **Backhand(ed)** - dado con la vuelta de la mano; (fig) irónico, equívoco, revés.

---

Atendiendo a su origen y trayectoria, parecería que el adjetivo más apropiado para "**backhanded**" sería "**enrevesado**". **Enrevesado** 1. adj. Difícil, intrincado, **oscuro** o que con dificultad se puede entender. De "revés" (Del lat. reversus, vuelto), 5. m. Vuelta o mudanza en el trato o en el genio.

Ejemplo;

- "Me aseguro que según mi altura, tenía una constitución privilegiada, un cumplido que no es nada halagador".

En este sentido **Backhanded compliments** (cumplido indirecto), haría referencia a algo que no es claro, es decir, algo "obscuro y un poco retorcido", como indica la voz "enrevesado", así de forma indirecta la persona que se expresa se vale soslayadamente de está estrategia para decir algo ingrato y desagradable, una especie de "revés en la charla", que hace la conversación molesta e irritante.

Existe un articulo que hace referencia a esta clase de "cumplidos indirectos" titulado ¿Qué es un **cumplido indirecto** y cómo responder?

> Si alguna vez ha recibido un **cumplido ambiguo**, sabe lo **confuso** que
> puede ser.
>
> Claro, **alguien te acaba de decir algo agradable, ¿o no?** ¿Cómo deberías
> responder?
>
> Según Merriam-Webster, un cumplido ambiguo es aquel que no es un
> cumplido en
>
> absoluto. De hecho, es realmente un insulto pasivo-agresivo disfrazado
> de elogio.
>
> **Los cumplidos indirectos** se te acercan sigilosamente. Son
> declaraciones
>
> **pasivo-agresivas** **redactadas para sonar como un cumplido, mientras que**
>
> **en realidad   son desagradables, mezquinas y críticas**.
>
> ....

https://ojodesabio.com/que-es-un-cumplido-indirecto-y-como-responder

---

**Otros ejemplos** de este tipo de comentarios;

- Sr. que fuerza tan grande tiene, como la de un león de peluche.
- Que ágil eres pareces un tronco.
- Las teorías dicen que el ser humano es el ser vivo más inteligente, pero parece que no habían contado con usted.
- Después de tres semanas con una chica siempre está usted hablando de que no encuentra su media naranja, no puede pensar que usted es más bien un limón.
- Que gracioso dibujas, pareces un parvulito.

...

Todo ello me llevo a pensar que en realidad todo esto hace referencia al adjetivo "inoportuno", el "**Backhanded compliments**", sería simplemente lo que nosotros llamamos "**Comentarios inoportunos**", inapropiados o impertinentes, de mal gusto principalmente para la persona a la que van dirigidos. Estos como aquellos pueden ser de todo tipo, irónicos, equívocos, enrevesados, ambiguos, sarcásticos...

- **Inoportuno**, inoportuna

Que sucede o se realiza en unas circunstancias o un momento desfavorables o

**contrarios**.

- **Importuno**, importuna

Incomodar o **molestar con una pretensión** o solicitud insistentes o poco oportunas, inconveniente, inapropiado, molesto...

---

Por último creo que también tenemos el adjetivo "**Indirecta**"  y la expresión "indirecta", "es una indirecta", "soltar una indirecta", "tirar una indirecta", "lanzar una indirecta", "hablar con indirectas"...

> Las indirectas suelen ser el arma preferida de las personas
>
> **pasivo-agresivas**, personas que recurren a insultos velados y dispersan
> culpas...
>
> Sus indirectas no son dardos disparados al azar, sino más bien misiles
>
> teledirigidos llenos de hostilidad que suelen hacer diana en sus
> víctimas
>
> provocando sentimientos de culpa, frustración e ira.

Los 3 tipos de indirectas que más daño causan

https://es.vida-estilo.yahoo.com/tipos-de-indirectas-150903234.html

**Indirecto, ta**

Del lat. indirectus.

1. adj. Que no va rectamente a un fin, aunque se encamine a él.
2. f. Dicho o medio de que alguien se vale para no significar explícita o claramente algo, y darlo, sin embargo, a entender.

https://dle.rae.es/indirecto

Dicho todo esto, no es de extrañar que en las traducciones se haya elegido la palabra "Ambiguo" para dar significado a "Backhanded", sea por desconocimiento o por una mala interpretación de la lengua, pues de alguna manera algo "Indirecto" o dicho de forma "**Indirecta**" no deja de ser también algo ambiguo en la manera de entenderse o interpretarse.